# make pandas.read_csv to not add lines with less columns delimiters than the main lines

Tags: python, pandas

Using `pandas.read_csv` with `on_bad_lines='warn'` option for lines with too many
columns delimiters, it work well, bad lines are not loaded and stderr catch the bad lines
numbers:

```py
    import pandas as pd
    from io import StringIO
    data = StringIO("""
    nom,f,nb
    bat,F,52
    cat,M,66,
    caw,F,15
    dog,M,66,,
    fly,F,61
    ant,F,21""")
    df = pd.read_csv(data, sep=',', on_bad_lines='warn')

    # b'Skipping line 4: expected 3 fields, saw 4\nSkipping line 6: expected 3 fields, saw 5\n'

    df.head(10)
    #    nom  f  nb
    # 0  bat  F  52
    # 1  caw  F  15
    # 2  fly  F  61
    # 3  ant  F  21
```

But in case the number of delimiter (here `sep=,`) is less  than the main, the line
is added adding `NaN`.:

```py
    import pandas as pd
    from io import StringIO
    data = StringIO("""
    nom,f,nb
    bat,F,52
    catM66,
    caw,F,15
    dog,M66
    fly,F,61
    ant,F,21""")
    df = pd.read_csv(data, sep=',', on_bad_lines='warn', dtype=str)
    df.head(10)

    #       nom    f   nb
    # 0     bat    F   52
    # 1  catM66  NaN  NaN            <==
    # 2     caw    F   15
    # 3     dog  M66  NaN            <==
    # 4     fly    F   61
    # 5     ant    F   21
```

Is there a way to make `read_csv` to not add lines with less columns delimiters than
the main lines ?

Note: I'm in a context of loading real big data files (e.g. hundred of millions of
lines, so the idea is not to propose any upfront grep/sed/awk processing but to take
benefit of fast `read_csv` bulk_load)

Comment: not ideal but probably `pd.read_csv().dropna(how='any')` would work.

Comment: @QuangHoang How can we differentiate if `NaN` comes from a bad line or a natural `NaN` that is on a proper line?

Comment: @NuriTaş we certainly can't, hence the *probably*.

Comment: The `on_bad_lines=warn` question me. Pandas team added the functionality to directly handle lines with more separators than the main lines, that's why it don't seems strange to me that some other pandas option could handle in the same way *lines with less separators than main lines*

Comment: related question on pandas github: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/48728

Answer (score 1):

`pd.read_csv()` is a very nice function that performs a well-defined
computation, but you desire a slightly different computation.
You wish to filter out all rows containing fewer than K fields.

> the idea is not to propose any upfront grep / sed / awk processing

You have rather constrained the solution space.
Apparently speed (elapsed time) or power efficiency (watts dissipated)
are motivating concerns.

You correctly observe that `grep` is quite fast and would be
a natural pre-processing stage.
One could store its filtered output to a temp file
which we feed to .read_csv(), potentially costing extra disk I/O.
A better solution would be to pipe its output
using the [subprocess library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

The original post mentions no `grep` timing results,
so it is unclear if overhead due to an extra child
process has been shown to be "too slow".
There's no throughput specification of N rows / second,
so it's unclear how this or any competing proposal
should be evaluated.

Note that [.read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) accepts a file-like object,
which could be a python generator that
inspects each row and only `yield`s suitable rows.

Given that you're gung ho on calling .read_csv(), a function
which doesn't quite compute what you want, it seems there's
little for it but to post-process its output and hope for the best.

Filtering out all `NaN`s might do, but that's a little on the drastic side.
There is some buggy generating process that produces "short" rows
with fewer than K fields.
If you know the minimum number of fields it's guaranteed to produce,
you could at least do appropriate column-wise filtering
to discard short rows.
Then you get to preserve true `NaN`s in the first several columns.
Good luck!